# Crop and save the image

Tags: xamarin.android

I used the following method as I wanted:
1-I want to open the camera, select image, crop and save the image in imageview
2- Crop and save a saved image  inside the device in imageview

erro

open camera
[image]

open gallery
[image]

full project
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tUSTyiq5qUPpaY6z2Jd1m2tv_HRE-QuL/view?usp=sharingusp=sharing

```
 public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
    {
        ImageView imageView;
        Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar toolbar;
        File file;
        Android.Net.Uri uri;
        Intent CamIntent, GalIntent, CropIntent;
        const int RequestPermissionCode = 1;



        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

            toolbar = FindViewById<Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);
            toolbar.Title = "Crop Image";
            toolbar.SetTitleTextColor(Android.Graphics.Color.White);
            SetSupportActionBar(toolbar);

       

            imageView = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.imageView);
            int permissionCheck = (int)ContextCompat.CheckSelfPermission(this, Manifest.Permission.Camera);
            if (permissionCheck == (int)Permission.Denied)
                RequestRuntimePermission();

        }

        private void RequestRuntimePermission()
        {
            if (ActivityCompat.ShouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.Permission.Camera))
                Toast.MakeText(this, "CAMERA permission will allows us to access CAMERA app", ToastLength.Short).Show();
            else
                ActivityCompat.RequestPermissions(this, new String[] { Manifest.Permission.Camera }, RequestPermissionCode);

        }

            public override bool OnCreateOptionsMenu(IMenu menu)
        {
            MenuInflater.Inflate(Resource.Menu.menu_main, menu);
            return true;
        }

        public override bool OnOptionsItemSelected(IMenuItem item)
        {
            if (item.ItemId == Resource.Id.btn_camera)
                CameraOpen();

            else if (item.ItemId == Resource.Id.btn_gallery)

                GalleryOpen();
            return true;
        }

        private void GalleryOpen()
        {
            GalIntent = new Intent(Intent.ActionPick, MediaStore.Images.Media.ExternalContentUri);
            StartActivityForResult(Intent.CreateChooser(GalIntent, "Select image from Gallery"), 2);
        }

        private void CameraOpen()
        {
            CamIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ActionImageCapture);
            file = new File(Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory, "file_image" + DateTime.Now + ".jpg");
            uri = Android.Net.Uri.FromFile(file);
            CamIntent.PutExtra(MediaStore.ExtraOutput, uri);
            CamIntent.PutExtra("return-data", true);
            StartActivityForResult(CamIntent, 0);
        }

        protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, [GeneratedEnum] Result resultCode, Intent data)
        {
            if (requestCode == 0 && resultCode == Result.Ok)
                CropImage();
            else if (requestCode == 2)
            {
                if (data != null)
                {
                    uri = data.Data;
                    CropImage();
                }
            }
            else if (requestCode == 1)
            {
                if (data != null)
                {
                    Bundle bundle = data.Extras;
                    Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap)bundle.GetParcelable("data");
                    imageView.SetImageBitmap(bitmap);
                }
            }
        }

        private void CropImage()
        {
            try
            {
                CropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
                CropIntent.SetDataAndType(uri, "image/*");

                CropIntent.PutExtra("crop", "true");
                CropIntent.PutExtra("outputX", 180);
                CropIntent.PutExtra("outputY", 180);
                CropIntent.PutExtra("aspectX", 3);
                CropIntent.PutExtra("aspectY", 4);
                CropIntent.PutExtra("scaleUpIfNeeded", true);
                CropIntent.PutExtra("return-data", true);

                StartActivityForResult(CropIntent, 1);
            }
            catch 
            {

            }
        }

        public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Permission[] grantResults)
        {
            switch (requestCode)
            {
                case RequestPermissionCode:
                    {
                        if (grantResults.Length > 0 && grantResults[0] == Permission.Granted)
                            Toast.MakeText(this, "Permission Granted", ToastLength.Short).Show();
                        else
                            Toast.MakeText(this, "Permission Canceled", ToastLength.Short).Show();
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1-I want to open the camera, select image, crop and save the image in imageview
>
> 2- Crop and save a saved image inside the device in imageview

If you want to do this, I suggest you can use **XamarinAndroidImageCropper** to do.

Firstly, install **XamarinAndroidImageCropper** by Manage Nuget package...., then add permissions to manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Using CropImageView like this:

```
<com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImageView
android:id="@+id/cropImageView"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:cropAspectRatioX="16"
app:cropAspectRatioY="9"
app:cropBackgroundColor="#88AA66CC"
app:cropBorderCornerColor="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
app:cropBorderCornerOffset="0dp"
app:cropBorderCornerThickness="5dp"
app:cropBorderLineColor="@android:color/holo_green_light"
app:cropBorderLineThickness="1dp"
app:cropGuidelines="on"
app:cropGuidelinesColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
app:cropInitialCropWindowPaddingRatio="0"
app:cropSnapRadius="0dp"/>
```

More detailed info, please take a look:

https://github.com/mikescandy/Xamarin-Cropper

Comment: Cherry Bu . Thanks all for the response and follow-up.
But when I modify the project as a whole, is it possible to modify only a small part of my project?
Crop the image after selecting it from the device and display it in imageview

Comment: @monemahmed Sure, you can do it by modifying this project.

Comment: HI Cherry Bu . Yes, the example You add is complete, but how is the image saved after the cropping process?
Another question, how to delete the blank background of the part that has been cut?

Comment: @monemahmed Do you try to modify sample according your requirement? Having some problem?

Comment: Do you try to modify sample according your requirement? Having some problem?Yes, I worked on the project and I cannot save the image or remove the background